# hide a div between two percentages of page of scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div which have a menu on Elementor .I'm going to hide between my nav and after reaching 80% of the page basicly my footer. The reason i'm doing this is to prevent it from interfering with footer.

I had found some codes and i did mine , but i just hided for the firts part  basically:

**y > PER**  AND I CANT PUT THIS PART WORKINK **y < PER2**

https://codepen.io/diogomaa/pen/JjMRgJL

```js
//PER is Percentage value
var PER = 45;
var PER2 = 60;
var yInPixel, totalHeight;

//If page if with dynamic height change totalHeight and yInPixel after Resize Event
$(document).ready(function() {
  totalHeight = $(this).height();
  
  yInPixel = totalHeight * (PER / 100) - window.innerHeight;
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y > yInPixel) {
  $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  if (y > PER && y < PER2 ) {
  document.getElementById("bottomMenu").style.visibility = "visible"; }
  } 
  else{
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomMenu">
<a> menu  </a> </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted another answer with a suggestion, but this one I believe is the actual solution you are seeking.

1. Change `document.getElementById("bottomMenu").style.visibility = "visible";` to `$('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();`. This is essentially what you are trying to do, but `bottomMenu` is a class, not an id, which is what `document.getElementById` would require.
2. You are comparing raw `scrollTop` values, which are in pixels, to percentages. You need to get the percentage first then compare apples to apples.

```js
//PER is Percentage value
var PER = 45;
var PER2 = 60;
var yInPixel, totalHeight;

//If page if with dynamic height change totalHeight and yInPixel after Resize Event
$(document).ready(function() {
  totalHeight = $(this).height();
  
  yInPixel = totalHeight * (PER / 100) - window.innerHeight;
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
  const y = $(this).scrollTop(),
      totalHeight = $(this).height(),
      curPercent = (y / totalHeight) * 100;

  if (curPercent > PER && curPercent < PER2 ) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } 
  else{
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
  
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomMenu">
<a> menu  </a> </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank u very much! It is exacly what i was trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

If your concerns are:

1. Bottom menu
2. Easy access to menu
3. Don't cover footer

I can suggest an elegant solution of making the menu appear on scroll up, and disappear on scroll down. Any time the user wants access to the menu, an initiation of scroll up (reflex is usually to go *up* for the menu anyways) will expose the menu. Footers, located on the bottom of a webpage, need to be scrolled *down* to reach, thus naturally hiding the menu in the process.

```js
var lastY = 0;
$('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();

//If page if with dynamic height change totalHeight and yInPixel after Resize Event

$(document).scroll(function() {
  const y = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (y < lastY)
      $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  else
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();

  lastY = y;
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

.bottomMenu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomMenu">
<a> menu  </a> </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```